# Is there a way to make properties of a widget reusable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I understand that making a widget reusable is good when you want to de-clutter your code but I think that it also reduces the code readibility and most often it's the properties (like `padding`,`color`,`shape`) of a widget (like `Container`,`Material`) which makes up the most clutter.

So, is there a way that I can make properties of a widget reusable rather than the widget itself.

For example, is there a way that I can make properties of this `Material`:

```cpp
Material(
  elevation: 4.0,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
    bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
  )),
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
  child: ...
```

Like this:

```cpp
Material(
  myMaterialProps: props,
  child: ...
```

Comment: no, there is no such way

Answer (score 0):

Is making your custom Widget fit your situation?

```
class MyCustomMaterial extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyCustomMaterial({
    required this.child,
    Key? key,
  }):super(key:key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Material(
      elevation: 4.0,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
        ),
      ),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

And use it as:

```
MyCustomMaterial(
  child: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your widget, the easiest way would be to create a custom widget, and set default values for the properties that won't change that often and make those properties optional.

To support variations of your widget, you can create factory methods that will receive only the properties that are different.

Here's a quick example (keep in mind it's just an example):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double elevation;
  final Clip clipBehaviour;
  final Color color;
  final Widget child;

  MyWidget(this.child, {double elevation, Clip clipBehaviour, Color color})
      : elevation = elevation ?? 4,
        clipBehaviour = clipBehaviour ?? Clip.hardEdge,
        color = color ?? Colors.green;

  factory MyWidget.withRedBorder(Widget child) {
    return MyWidget(
      child,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        elevation: 4.0,
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
        )),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
        child: child);
  }
}
```